# SSH: Execute different shell based on public key used

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

I want to allow ssh access to a specific account, but if I connect using a specific puclic key, I should be dropped to a full shell, otherwise to a restricted one.

Example:

> I connect with ssh to user@myhost.com using the public key ABCDEF (correctly set up in authorized_keys) and I get a /bin/zsh shell
>
> If I connect to user@myhost.com with a password or another public key, I get a /bin/rsh shell

My idea was to create a custom intermediate shell (IE: /bin/mysh), check the key used and execute the correct shell from there, but I don't know how to check which key was used (or if it's possible at all).

env doesn't seem to contain anything useful.

Any ideas on how to do this or other possible solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe 2 different users with same UID, but different shells.

Comment: question - if you have the "limited" key launch, say, `/bin/ksh`, what prevents them from starting `/bin/bash` after login?

Comment: @warren, it would not be a "real" shell like ksh, so they wouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: @LatinSuD: it must be the same user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `command` option in the `authorized_keys` file on the key you want to use an alternate shell with. See the `sshd(8)` man page, **AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT** section, for details.

Comment: this is how, also can limit what can be done with the connection per key, meaning port forwarding etc